# In R Datatable is their a way to conditionally add a plus sign to a number?

Tags: r, datatables, formatting, dt

I have a column in my table that is a percent change so I would like to have it show as plus or minus. The issue is I still want it to be sortable so it needs to be numeric rather than a string.

I assume something can be done in the datatable formatting to add a plus to anything above 0 but can't figure it out based on the documentation. I need the 4th column to have a plus/minus in front. This is my starting point:

```
  datatable(temp,rownames=F,options = list(dom='t'))%>%
  formatStyle("Change",
              backgroundColor  = styleInterval(c(-.10,-.075, -.05, -.025,-.0175, 0,.0175, .025, .05, .075, .10), 
                                               c('#f79539','#fab83e','#f7e38f','#fffcc9','#fffee6', '#ffffff','#ffffff','#fffee6','#fffcc9','#f7e38f','#fab83e', '#f79539' )))  %>%
  formatPercentage(c(2:4), 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `render`:

```
library(DT)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row) {",
  "  if(type === 'display') {",
  "    var sign = data > 0 ? '+' : '-';",
  "    return sign + data;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

df <- data.frame(
  Val = c("A", "B"), 
  x = c(-1, 1)
)
datatable(df, 
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(targets = 2, render = JS(render))
            )
          )
)
```

Comment: It seems that when I am using the formatPercentage on it that overrides the use of the render. Is their a way to do the format percentage through the render? I am not familar with that code so I do not know how to make that change.

Comment: @bpheazye `return sign + data + '%';`

Comment: Thank you Stephane!
Just to complete for those finding this later to fully simulate the formatPercentage function use tofixed
`render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row) {",
  "  if(type === 'display') {",
  "    var sign = data > 0 ? '+' : '-';",
  "    return sign + (100*data).toFixed(2) + '%';",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)`